# What is the proper way to reset a modal content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

So, I have a bootstrap modal which has three "steps". I have three `.modal-content` div inside  the `.modal` div, the last two with `display:none`. When the user presses a button, I do some animation to bring the next step.

What happens is that I have several inputs and stuff like that inside this modal. So if you open the modal, type things, close, and open again, the modal will open with the information you had typed before.

To solve this problem, I created a function to reset everything inside the modal (cleaning inputs, and a loot of another things you can do, for example, you can click a button to add another input field in the modal - so for reset the state I need to check the length of the divs and leave just one again) and I was wondering if there is another easy way to do that without executing the function every time you press the button to open the modal.

I tried several things, like cloning the original html and every time you click the button, I delete the current modal html and insert the one I copied, but it always got buggy because some events of links and inputs never works, some do (and I don't know why).

I'm using jQuery and Knockout.js in my application

Comment: When I did this I created a reset method as you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a sub model object in an observable. You can then use a with binding on the sub model object. To reset you can then just create a new object and assign it to the observable.

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.subModel = ko.observable(new SubModel());

    self.reset = function () {
        self.subModel(new SubModel());
    };
};

var SubModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.field1 = ko.observable();
    self.field2 = ko.observable();
    self.field3 = ko.observable();
    self.field4 = ko.observable();
};


<div data-bind="with: subModel">
    <input type="text" data-bind="field1"/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="field2"/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="field3"/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="field4"/>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: reset">Reset</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a5X6f/1/

Comment: Nice approach! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can reset a viewmodel using the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

Consider this data, which is the data you start with:

```
var initData = {
    firstInput: "First Init Value",
    secondInput: "Second Init Value",
    thirdInput: "Third Init Value",
    showSecond: false
};
```

First, load the data you want with the plugin: `ko.mapping.fromJS(initData, {}, this);`

Then you can create a `reset` function that looks like this:

```
this.reset = function () {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(initData, this);
}
```

When you call this function, your viewmodel will be updated with the init data, which will be like a reset.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/5K5fV/)